# How to get list of objects in bucket, using Appercept AWS SDK for Delphi?

Tags: amazon-web-services, delphi, amazon-s3, delphi-11-alexandria

I try to get list of objects in root bucket, but it returns 0 objects =( In fact, there are three objects there. I am sure about that.

```
uses
  AWS.S3, AWS.Core;
...

procedure TMainForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  opt:IAWSOptions;
begin
  ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown:=true;
  opt:=TAWSOptions.Create;
  opt.AccessKeyId:='*****';
  opt.SecretAccessKey:='*****';
  opt.Endpoint:=TAWSEndpoint.Create('https://s3.storage.selcloud.ru');
  opt.Region:='ru-1';
  s3aws:=TS3Client.Create(opt);
  var Response := s3aws.ListBuckets;
  StatusMemo.Lines.Add('Root bucket(s):');
  for var Bucket in Response.Buckets do begin
    StatusMemo.Lines.Add( '- ' + Bucket.Name );
    StatusMemo.Lines.Add( '- Objects: ' + IntToStr(Bucket.Objects.Count) );
    for var ObjName in Bucket.Objects do
      StatusMemo.Lines.Add( '- ' + ObjName.Key );
  end;
end;
```

The connection works, the root bucket arrives, but Bucket.Objects.Count returns 0
In python via boho3 all works correctly, checked, but I need solution in Delphi

Comment: You know you can mix Python code into a Delphi app? Just in case you don't find a Delphi-only solution...

Comment: I know about it, but I'd like to avoid another language integration. It will be a server-side app, using interpreted language in body - not correctly solution

Answer (score 0):

The [`ListBuckets`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_ListBuckets.html) command only gives you the names of the buckets that are owned by the sender. To get the objects, you need to send a separate [`ListObjects`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_ListObjects.html) or [ListObjectsV2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_ListObjectsV2.html) command for each bucket. Refer to your SDK's documentation for how to send that command.